# Create javascript string with conditional and non conditional variables

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm creating a single string using some defined variables like so:

```
var name = 'John';
var business = 'Google';
var email = name + ' registered the business ' + business;
```

In reality this is from a form submission so the variables will be set in a form and sent to my NodeJS backend to create this string. The user may or may not enter a message. I've created an if statement to add it to the string if they have:

`if (message) email += '<br /><br />Message: ' + message;`

The problem is when I expand this logic, it can get very messy. For example if I want to add several conditional variables to various points in the middle of the original string. Is there a way to do the conditional logic inside the initial string build?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a ternary operator.  It can still get messy, but it reduces "if" everywhere.

```
var email = name + ' registered ' + business
            + (message ? '<br /><br />Message: ' : '')  // conditional line
            + more_stuff...;
```

Comment: Just what I was after. It was this style of inline code that would stop it getting too complex or messy. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you could structure the code to clean things up.  A simple solution would be creating an object that keeps track of your various inputs, and then you could loop through that object to append all necessary items.

For example:

```
var obj = {
  message: messageField,
  messageTwo: messageTwoField
}

for (keys in obj){
  if (key == message && obj.key) {
    //append the string to a specific place
  }
}
```

There are many ways to potentially solve this, but by storing everything in one object that can help to clean things up.  Also, the if statement is conditional based on the key name and if there is a value assigned to that key name.  This of course is just my opinion on how you could approach this, the size and complexity of the app could greatly change this answer.